# Firestore Rules: Only show documents if document field is false

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a NSFW system where it checks the document if it is NSFW and if it is it updates the document field `isNSFW` to `true`. That works just fine but now I wanted to not show those documents to all users via settings a rule instead of querying it out.

This is what I have but it's not working...
javascript

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
    }
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
    match /docs/{doc} { // THIS HERE
        allow read: if resource.data.isNSFW == false; 
    }
}
```

I tried adding `request.` before the `resource` and it still didn't work.

UPDATE:
javascript

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // match /{document=**} {
    //  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    // }
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if currentUser().uid != null;
    }
    match /docs {
      allow read: if existingData().users[currentUser().uid] == false; 
    }
    match /docs/{doc} {
      allow write: if currentUser().uid != null;
    }
  }
  // MARK - Funcs ---------------
  function existingData() {
    return resource.data
  }

  function incomingData() {
    return request.resource.data
  }

  function currentUser() {
    return request.auth
  }

  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
    }
}
```

Getting error:

```
Listen for Query(docs where users.`40S88coPQObEWSeiYMZIJlIKJkI2` == false order by __name__) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to be certain why it isn't working. But remember: rules are not filters on their own. Your code also needs to explicitly query for documents where `isNSFW` is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Datastore, you can simply query [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)
 your data:

```js
var myDB = db.collection("YOUR-DB-COLLECTION");
var query = myDB.where("isNSFW", "==", false);
```

If you are using GCP datastore, you do it this other way [2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#query_interface):

```js
const query = datastore
  .createQuery('YOUR-COLLECTION')
  .filter('isNSFW', '=', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matches are not nested correctly.  They should be inside the block that starts with `match /databases/{database}/documents`.  Also, you should strongly consider removing the match on `/{document=**}` because that will let everyone read any document in the database if they're logged in, ignoring all other rules.

Comment: Listen for Query(docs where users.`40S88coPQObEWSeiYMZIJlIKJkI2` == false order by __name__) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null} is what I'm getting now